# Get positional data from index on a 2D-field

Tags: geometry, tile

Say I had three variables (On a 2D-field):

NumSquares,
WindowSize (Both X and Y has this value),
Index

So if, for example, NumSquares were 8, WindowSize 256 and Index was at 64; How would the algorithm to get positional data out of these variables look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "positional data" you mean coordinates on the grid. And index means position of the tile in linearized array calculated with formula `X + width * Y`. Then:

```
X = index % width
Y = index / width
```

I'm not sure what language you are working in, so just to be sure: % is modulo, / is in this context **integer division**.

Comment: Ah, exactly what I needed. Thank you for solving two of my problems for today: My original question, and my sudden lack of proper words :D Oh, and I´m working in C# :)